# How can I use the delete method in Angular to pass data in body?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, delete-method

I have the below AWS lambda function which I have created with the intention of defining soft deleting and hard deleting my product.

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => { 
    const product = JSON.parse(event.body);
    let sql;
    let msg;
    let values;
   if (product.action == 'delete')  {
        sql = "UPDATE product_table SET isDeleted=1, deletedon=? WHERE product_id=?";
        msg = 'The product has been sucessfully deleted';
        values = new Date();
    } else if (product.action == 'restore') {
        sql = "UPDATE product_table SET isDeleted=0, deletedon=? WHERE product_id=?";
        msg = 'The product has been successfully restored';        
        values = null;
    }
    
    try {    
        const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.getConnection(function (err) {   
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);     
                }
            connection.query(sql, [values, product.product_id], function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {  
                        console.log("Error->" + err);     
                        reject(err);        
                    }         
                    resolve(result);  
                });     
            });  
        }); 
        
        return { 
            statusCode: 200,  
            body: JSON.stringify(msg)
        };     
    } catch (err) {    
        return {   
            statusCode: 400,   
            body: JSON.stringify(err.message) 
        };
    }
};
```

The idea is to use a single delete method from API and pass id and action values in the JSON object to goggle between delete and restore.

I was able to get this working on Postman, but not from my Angular Application. I am passing the values sam as I would do with POST method. Can you please help me on what I am missing?

Below is the angular code:

```js
deleteProductData(product_id:number,action:string) {
      const header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
          .append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
      const httpOptions = {
          headers: header,
          body:JSON.stringify({ "product_id": product_id,"action":action })
      };    
     return this.http.delete<any>(this.productGetUrl, httpOptions);
  }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Actually that's the thing. I don't receive any response from the server end at all!

Comment: added the angular code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issues. My configurations were incorrect.

I was trying to send the data for the delete method inside a 'body', not knowing that the delete method only supported queryStringParameters or pathParameters.

I was able to fix the issue by refactoring my backend similar to how I configured a GET request.